# How to change color of part of dynamic string in swift %@?

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I am using the following placeholder in my string: **%@**

For instance my string is **String(format:** **"greetings %@", str)**

How can I provide a specific color for this dynamic placeholder?

Comment: I was talking about a string which we use in our app. Yes I know about NSAttributedString, but I don't know how can I change color for a part of the string, which is dynamically set with Viktor, for example

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the attributes for a `NSRange` within an attributed string. But rather than build it with a format string and retroactively going back and updating the attributes for a `NSRange`, I’d just create an attributed string for the string to be appended, setting its attributes before you append it:

```
let name = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])

let greeting = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "greetings ")
greeting.append(name)

label.attributedText = greeting
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: this works with the string "greeting", but how about loading NSLocalized string? I need a dynamic approach, which would not depend on a particular string. Is it possible?